# Por qúe el alert se repite?

Tags: javascript

Intento recorrer todos los `inputs` del documento y luego agregarle a cada uno de ellos la propiedad `onblur`, pero el `alert` **siempre aparece**, por qué?

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
  (function(){
    for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
      console.log(inputs[i].id);
      inputs[i].setAttribute('onblur','alert(\'Bucle\')');
    }
  })();
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="g1" type="text">
  <input id="g2" type="text">
  <input id="g3" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solo me gusta aprender para no cometer los mismos errores

Comment: @A.Cedano - Y que tiene que ver eso con el _problema_ que tiene el OP? Está poniendo el `alert` como valor....

Comment: @A.Cedano - Sigo sin entender el problema...creo que te estás equivocando... `setAttribute(atributo= onblur => valor=alert (o lo quesea)`

Comment: Efectivamente, ha sido un equívoco @aldanux. Borrando comentarios. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entras en un bucle porque no puedes o mejor dicho es imposible de salir del `onblur` mientras estás en `alert`.

`está en blur -> alert -> cierras alert -> está en blur -> alert... infinito`

Una solución seria de cambiar de `onblur` a `onchange`

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    
  (function(){
      
    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++ ) {
        
      console.log(inputs[i].id);
      inputs[i].setAttribute('onchange','alert('+i+')');
    }
      
  })();
 
});
```

```html
<input id="g1" type="text">
<input id="g2" type="text">
<input id="g3" type="text">
```

o usar algún plugin de modal/notificaciones.

Comment: Tu código no me muestra ningún alert

Comment: @EduardoSebastian - Es que tienes que escribir algo y salir del campo... es como funciona el `onchange`....

Comment: Ah gracias, mucho tiempo sin usar onchange